# nginx-rtmp-module always on even when there is no live user

Tags: nginx

In documentation of nginx-rtmp-module (https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#exec) for Exec directive is written:

When publishing stops the process is terminated.

But how to make exec to continue executing even when there is no publish streams, no live user?

Answer (score 0):

Try `exec_static`.
This config execute command line when nginx is start